# Mediawiki markup on RSS

Tags: rss, mediawiki, wiki-markup

Is it possible to remove the markup wiki language from the RSS feed and only show the article content?

Because I am using different template like info-boxes etc. and when people click the RSS link it show all the template markup and all the unnecessary coding that people don't really care. I been trying to find a good tutorial or help where I can accomplish this.
[Screentshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyX6E.png)

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to achieve. You can just link to [[Special:Newpages]] if that's what you want to show.  You can even transclude that like this: `{{Special:Newpages}}`.

Comment: I want to remove all the wiki markup coding on the RSS I marked on the screenshot what I want remove

Comment: This RSS has been designed to allow wiki contributors to track recent changes. It's not mainly targeted to wiki readers. You probably would like a custom RSS feed generated with information extracted from the infobox parameters and the first paragraph of the article.

Answer (score 0):

As Dereckson says, no, it's not possible. Feeds are just an alternate way to consume [recent changes](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Recent_changes).

The ability to consume recent changes in parsed format essentially equates the feature request for visual diffs (HTML diffs). Will be possible at some point with Parsoid.